# SSL and encryption

Tags: ssl

Im mainly asking for an explaination. Ive got a website using virtuemart on joomla. I also have a client that doesnt want to use any gateway payment programs. at the moment im using a simple form for credit card details which of course is terrible.

I have bought a SSL and waiting for that to be activiated.

Would this SSL do for encryption forms? or will I need to edit the form aswell so its encrypted.

What they used to have was a credit card payment area where you put your details in and click submit. they (the company) got an email with a link that you then clicked on to view an encrypted email with the clients credit card details.

I have never used virtuemart before nor SSL. So some help would be awesome.

Dont mind removing the form but need someway to have a credit card form on the site that is secure.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have bought an SSL

You have bought an SSL *certificate.* That identifies your site to clients when you both use the SSL *protocol*, which performs authentication, encryption, and various other things to assure privacy and integrity.

You need to define *access to* the form so that it requires HTTPS rather than HTTP.

Comment: Just found where [buying "*an SSL*" came from](http://www.godaddy.com/ssl/ssl-certificates.aspx?ci=9039) (scroll down "*About our SSLs*", "*Why you need an SSL*", "*Why buy a Go Daddy SSL?*", "*One SSL covers unlimited servers*", ...). Unbelievable, coming from people whose job it is to know about all this...